# Facebook stream won't appear on website

Tags: javascript, html

I've read the previous problems for other people in this situation but none of them rectify my issue.

Nothing shows up at all on my website when trying to implement this facebook like/stream to a website.. any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<title><hi></title></head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>






<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Aberliquidscreed" data-width="250px" data-height="400px" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
</body>
</htm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing your facebook SDK and facebook API call  FB.init

Step one: (put this inside your header html tag and update the appid_goes_here with your id)

```
   <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APPID_goes_here',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Step Two: (anywhere in content replace appid_goes_here with your api key)

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=appid_goes_here&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Ah I see, because im not the creator of the facebook page I guess the API key isn't attainable without admin permissions for the facebook page?

Comment: Goto https://developers.facebook.com/  signup for a developers account, create yourself an Web App to get an API key.